# get Access Token through Google OAuth and save it in db

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

i want to save access token from Google OAuth i have already write a code but the access token do not save in db when i check it here is code which i have done.

code in Startup.Auth.cs

```
var g = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions

        {

            ClientId = "356947391093-0mgql4ubb8708d24rp1c3d4akg508lu1.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "kobUYK0tyFpBrVXZjL9a-6Yx",
            //CallbackPath="",
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:accesstoken", ctx.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        };
        // restrict the retrieved information to just signin information
        g.Scope.Add("openid");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(g);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Google Access Tokens are good for one hour.  You might want to consider saving the RefreshToken instead.

Comment: how can i implement the RefreshToken will you please provide me some sample code ?